# Total x the price is not working - Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

cheems

[image]

problemsencountered

[image]

Hello. I'm trying to do a mini business management using class, objects etc. What im trying to do is, whenever I input quantity of the items, it will multiply to the price and will get a total after I input something in 3 items.(Sticker, shirt and shoes) I tried to change it every time I got an error but still getting a new error after changing. I got list not callable or not subscriptable after changing things. I also got an error "Student not defined" before even tho the class is named "Student". Im also having errors in line 25 and 13 which I think I input correctly. Please see the attached photos/code for reference. I'm going to use this code with tkinter. Thank you in advance.

```
class Student():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.sticker =[]
        self.shirt = []
        self.shoes = []

    def getData(self, m1,m2, m3):
        self.sticker.append(m1)
        self.shirt.append(m2)
        self.shoes.append(m3)

    def displayData(self):
        return('Total sales are:' + self.average())
    def total(self):
        return(self.sticker[0]*5, self.shirt[1]*200, self.shoes[2]*1000)

    def average (self):
        return(self.sticker[0] + self.shirt[1] + self.shoes[2])
m1 = (input('Enter the quantity of sticker sold: '))
m2 = (input('Enter the quantity of shirt sold: '))
m3 = (input('Enter the quantity of the shoes sold: '))

s1 = Student()
s1.getData(m1, m2, m3)
s1.displayData()
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Kenken\Desktop\Kenken - Python\businesshit.py", line 25, in <module>   
    s1.displayData()
  File "c:\Users\Kenken\Desktop\Kenken - Python\businesshit.py", line 14, in displayData
    print('Total sales are:' + self.total())
  File "c:\Users\Kenken\Desktop\Kenken - Python\businesshit.py", line 16, in total
    return(self.sticker[0]*5, self.shirt[1]*200, self.shoes[2]*1000)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: First don't post code in image.  The function `average()` is an inner function inside `total()`.  The indentation of `average()` should be the same as other functions.

Comment: All the arrays have only one item, so `self.shirt[1]` and `self.shoes[2]` will raise the exception.  Also your code has nothing related to `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Student():
    def __init__(self):
        self.sticker = []
        self.shirt=[]
        self.shoes=[]
    def getData(self, m1,m2, m3):
        self.sticker.append(m1)
        self.shirt.append(m2)
        self.shoes.append(m3)
    def displayData(self):
        return('Total sales are:' + self.average())
    def total(self):
        return(self.sticker[0]*5, self.shirt[0]*200, self.shoes [0]*1000)
    def average (self):
        return(self.sticker[0] + self.shirt[0] + self.shoes[0])
m1=(input('Enter the quantity of sticker sold: '))
m2=(input('Enter the quantity of shirt sold: '))
m3=(input('Enter the quantity of the shoes sold: '))
s1 = Student()
s1.getData(m1, m2, m3)
s1.displayData()
```

You should give a try to this code.

There are two mistakes in your code:

1)You should write all the methods in a class with same indentation.But in your code the method average was not aligned with other methods.

2)You appended the elements into empty list so their index was at position 0.so in total and average methods in Student class you need to use the index 0 while accessing elements in shirts and shoes as shirts[0] and shoes[0]

In order to print the total value use print(s1.displayData())